# MySQL - Combining multiple queries + counts

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I'm attempting to combine a few queries and can't seem to nail it down. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here are the statements:

```
SELECT
I.id,
I.custname,
I.custemail,
I.sku,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts), '%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts
FROM images I
WHERE I.stat = 0

SELECT
COUNT(*) AS total1
FROM images
WHERE stat = 1 AND sku = ?

SELECT
COUNT(*) AS total2
FROM images
WHERE stat = 1 
AND sku IN (SELECT subsku FROM combo WHERE sku = ?)
```

Right now I'm using the 3 separate queries and am using code to add the two totals and display them. But I now need to be able to sort by the sum of the totals, so I'd like to get all of that data into one statement.. something like:

```
SELECT
I.id,
I.custname,
I.custemail,
I.sku,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts), '%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts,
SUM(total1+total2)
FROM images I
WHERE I.stat = 0
```

But I'm unsure how to do that. I tried the code below, but it failed:

```
SELECT 
I.id, 
I.custname, 
I.custemail, 
I.sku, 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts),'%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total1 FROM images WHERE stat = 1 AND (
        sku IN (
            SELECT subsku FROM combo WHERE sku = I.sku
    ) OR sku = I.sku)
) AS skuct 
FROM images I 
WHERE stat = 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

**UPDATE**

First off thanks to everyone who has offered assistance. I've been working on the query and think I'm getting closer, but I'm now hitting a 'subquery returns more than 1 row' error:

```
SELECT 
I.id, 
I.custname, 
I.custemail, 
I.sku,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts), '%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM images
    WHERE stat = 1 
    AND sku = I.sku
    OR sku IN(
        SELECT subsku FROM combo WHERE sku = I.sku
    )
GROUP BY sku
) AS total
FROM images I
WHERE stat = 0
```

The problem is that the subquery `SELECT subsku FROM combo WHERE...` returns a resultset (0+ rows) vs a scalar. If I can figure out that part, I think this will work.

Comment: What do you want to do? Sort by `SUM`?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to be able to `ORDER BY` the `SUM` of the totals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select I.id, I.custname, I.custemail, I.sku
    , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts), '%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts
    ,   (
        Select Sum( Case
                    When I1.sku = ? Then 1
                    When I1.sku In( Select subsku From combo As S1 Where S1.sku = ? ) Then 1
                    Else 0
                    End ) As Total
        From images As I1
        Where I1.stat = 1
        ) As Total
From images As I
Where stat = 0
```

Another solution

```
Select I.id, I.custname, I.custemail, I.sku
    , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts), '%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts
    ,   (
        Select Count(*)
        From images As I1
        Where I1.stat = 1
            And (
                I1.sku = ?
                Or I1.sku In ( Select subsku From combo As S1 Where S1.sku = ? )
                )
        ) As Total
From images As I
Where stat = 0
```

**Addition**

Another possible solution:

```
Select I.id, I.custname, I.custemail, I.sku
    , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts), '%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts
    ,   (
        Select Sum( Cnt )
        From    (
                Select Count(*) As Cnt
                From images As I1
                    Left Join combo As C1
                        On C1.sku = I1.sku
                Where I1.stat = 1
                    And I1.sku = ?
                    And C1.PrimaryKeyCol Is Null
                Union All 
                Select Count( Distinct I1.PrimaryKeyCol )
                From images As I1
                    Join combo As C1
                        On C1.sku = I1.sku
                Where I1.stat = 1
                    And I1.sku = ?
                ) As Z
        ) As Total
From images As I
Where stat = 0
```

**Edit**

If you are looking for the count *by image* in which you correlate the counts to the outer table `images` sku column, that's entirely different. For that, I would use a derived table:

```
Select I.id, I.custname, I.custemail, I.sku
    , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts), '%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts
    , Counts.Total
From images As I
    Join    (
            Select Z.sku, Sum(Z.Cnt) As Total
            From    (
                    Select I1.sku, Count(*) As Cnt
                    From images As I1
                        Left Join combo As C1
                            On C1.sku = I1.sku
                    Where I1.stat = 1
                        And C1.PrimaryKeyCol Is Null
                    Group By I1.sku
                    Union All 
                    Select I1.sku, Count( Distinct I1.PrimaryKeyCol )
                    From images As I1
                        Join combo As C1
                            On C1.sku = I1.sku
                    Where I1.stat = 1
                    Group By I1.sku
                    ) As Z
            Group By Z.sku
            )  As Counts
        On Counts.sku = I.sku
Where stat = 0
```

Obviously in all cases, replace `PrimaryKeyCol` with the name of the actual primary key column of the `images` table.

Comment: This works (although I had to remove the `S1.` from the second `WHEN`), however it takes a very long time to run (~80s). `EXPLAIN` shows an index on 'sku' but it's still pulling all of the rows twice.

Comment: @greatcaesarsghost - I've corrected the alias (`S1`) problem which was a typo. The alias was supposed to be on the table `combo` not the column. I've also posted another solution.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you sooner. I was out yesterday. The second solution works, but it's still too slow (90+s). I'm changing the "?"s to `I.sku`, though, as I won't be passing a variable (I just need the totals in the result set). That's no doubt what's slowing it. I'm just not sure how to go about doing it. Currently leaning towards just tossing it all in an array and sorting on a key.

Comment: @greatcaesarsghost - Is there an index on `images.sku`, `images.stat` and `combo.subsku`?

Comment: Good question! I had to check. The following indexes exist: `images(sku)`, `images(stat)`, `images(sku,stat)`, `combo(subsku)`. But no multi-column/multi-table indexes. Is it even possible to index across tables without some foreign key?

Comment: @greatcaesarsghost - I posted another possible solution.

Comment: I'm sure the fault is on me, not you, but I can't get the 3rd one to work. I think the problem is the `?`s . In a prepared statement I'd pass the value of the variable to that location, but as I'm trying to get the value for all skus (not just one passed sku), it's having to lookup all of the rows vs. 1. So `WHERE I1.sku = I.sku` causes the issue. Sadly, I don't get to use complicated SQL on a daily basis at work, so I'm a little out of my element here. I do appreciate you sticking with me and trying to help.

Comment: @greatcaesarsghost - The inner query starting with `Select Sum...` never joins to the outer `images` table per your original request. Is it the case that you want the outer `images` table correlated to the inner count? If so that's different and I would do the query different.

Comment: @greatcaesarsghost - Btw, by "original request" I mean in the original verison of your post, you weren't asking for the total *by image* but rather the overall total.

Comment: I definitely could have worded the original request better. I have attempted to rectify it through an update on the original post. The existing code takes 3 separate queries and combines them: the first gets all the images, the second gets a count of status 1 images with that same sku and the third gets another count. I just need to combine all of that data into one result, if possible, so that the recordset contains all of the information along with a count of available images. Again, I apologize for any confusion and thank you for your patience.

Comment: The latest edit did the trick! Thank you so much! And I learned something to boot, so that's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered changing the `WHERE` logic to perform the count in one.
Assuming the two counts are mutually exclusive you could just `OR` the two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cross join . . .

```
select t1.*, t2.total1, t3.total2
from 
(
  SELECT I.id, I.custname, I.custemail, I.sku,
      DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(I.ts), '%l:%i:%s %p, %c/%e/%Y') AS ts
  FROM images I
  WHERE I.stat = 0
) t1 
cross join
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total1
  FROM images
  WHERE stat = 1 AND sku = ?
) t2 
cross join
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total2
  FROM images
  WHERE stat = 1  AND sku IN (SELECT subsku FROM combo WHERE sku = ?) 
) t3
```

You might be able to make this more efficient, since they are all going after the same table.  A single aggregation with a case statement per `WHERE` clause would probably be more efficient.

Comment: The problem I'm having with `CROSS JOIN` is needing the count for each sku in the first table. `sku = ?` would have to change to `sku = t1.sku` but the joined table wouldn't have that information, right?